# Что главное для Rest приложения?

Tags: rest

Что главное для Rest приложение? Это то, что методы контроллеров должны называться в определенном стиле или то, что пользователь должен носить свою сессию всегда с собой, или что-то еще? Может быть все вместе, плюс какие-то дополнения

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать: http://www.restapitutorial.ru/lessons/whatisrest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Реализация](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/ws-restfu/index.html) Web-сервисов REST следует четырем базовым принципам проектирования:

> 1. Явное использование HTTP-методов.
> 2. Несохранение состояния.
> 3. Предоставление URI, аналогичных структуре каталогов.
> 4. Передача данных в XML, JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) или в обоих форматах.

Исходя из изложенных выше принципов, можно сделать вывод, что [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) отлично подходит и используется в основном для построения *API-интерфейсов*, "заставляя" придерживаться определенного стиля, понятного для всех.

Но, *REST* не налаживает никаких "архитектурных" ограничений на приложение. Т.е. название контроллеров в архитектурном шаблоне [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) для соответствия архитектуре *REST* не играет **никакой** роли.

Использование сторонних [API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) для клиентского приложения *практически всегда* предполагает сохранения состояния сессию на стороне клиента (т. е. нужно "тащить" ее с собой от запроса к запросу).

Вы не до конца понимаете зачем нужен REST и как его реализовывать, поэтому у Вас возникает такие непонятные вопросы...